# Ubuntu 15.10 GRUB menu option disappeared after updating Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a computer system with multiple disks.  I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed as my main OS, but I also have Windows 7 installed on a separate disk.  I more recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on yet another disk and when I did, the installer apparently saw that I had 14.04 installed also and created a boot menu with both 15.10 as the default and 14.04 as an option.  This was not what I intended, I intended to switch between 14.04 and 15.10 via firmare boot options and have the two Ubuntu installs unaware of each other unless I decided to mount the other disk, but whatever, everything was working OK.  I used 15.10 for a while and then booted back into 14.04 after maybe a few months.

Unsurprisingly, the 14.04 install had a large number of updates pending, so I went ahead and updated using the Software Updater as usual.  I think one of the updates was for GRUB.  When I rebooted after the updates were installed, the option to boot into 15.10 was no longer available.  I tried using the boot-repair utility on my live Ubuntu 14.04 USB drive, but it suggested I do something that looked potentially dangerous to me, namely:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -y --force-yes dmraid
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dmraid -ay
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -y --force-yes lvm2
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common grub-common:i386 shim-signed linux-signed*
```

so I cancelled that action and had it generate a boot info report which can be found here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15146374/

Can anybody help me figure out what went wrong and how I should go about fixing it?  If it is safe to use the boot-repair utility's suggestion I can do that.  I guess I can even reinstall 15.10 if need be, but I think the 15.10 data is still there and I want to understand what happened so I can prevent it from happening in the future.  Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the Ubuntu 15.10 disk does not show as a boot option  in my firmware boot options when I reboot either, neither when in normal UEFI mode nor when CSM is enabled, so I can't boot into 15.10 that way either, but I can see the 15.10 disk and all the partitions when I boot into 14.04.

Comment: The boot loaders are not in sda, sdb, and sdc - as can be seen in the beginning lines of the boot info script. Thing is, the last OS installed, always overwrites the GRUB2 loader with it's own. Maybe the steps here can help you: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: The absence of boot loaders in `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` is *not* a problem, since the computer boots in EFI mode. On such a system, the boot loader is stored as an ordinary file on the EFI System Partition (ESP), which is `/dev/sda1` in this case. (`/dev/sdb1` is also an ESP, but seems to be unused.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your output correctly, Ubuntu 15.10 is installed in an LVM logical volume called `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root`; however, the script has been unable to identify the filesystem on that logical volume. This probably means that either:

- The script can't detect Ubuntu 15.10 because of a bug or misconfiguration -- This is the more optimistic cause, but it doesn't really help much because it means you're missing data. You might first try `ls /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root` from Ubuntu 14.04. If the file isn't present, you may need to install some LVM components in Ubuntu 14.04 (try `sudo apt-get install lvm2`). If that causes `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root` to appear, try `sudo update-grub` and see if that helps. If `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root` is already present, then you could try `sudo blkid /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root`, and/or try mounting it, to verify that the filesystem is intact.
- The filesystem is damaged -- If the filesystem on `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root` is damaged, then you're in trouble. If you've got any critical data on that installation, you should first do a low-level backup, as in `sudo dd if=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root of=/path/to/lots/of/space/u1510-backup.img`. You can then try `sudo fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root` to repair it. If the repair is successful, doing a `sudo update-grub` might bring it back to the boot menu.

An entirely different approach is to try another boot method. In particular, my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) might help:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of rEFInd from [its downloads page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a boot medium from rEFInd.
3. If Secure Boot is enabled, disable it. (You can re-enable it later, if you like.)
4. Boot to the rEFInd medium. It should show options for both of your Ubuntu installations, although the labels may not be clear. The 14.04 installation will probably refer to booting `boot\vmlinuz-3.13-*`, whereas the 15.10 installation will probably refer to booting `vmlinuz-4.2.0-*` (no leading `boot\`, and a higher kernel version number).
5. Highlight the 15.10 entry and hit F2 or Insert twice. This will open a simple text-mode line editor with kernel options.
6. Add `ro root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root` to the boot options.
7. Hit Enter.

If rEFInd boots Ubuntu 15.10, you can install the rEFInd Debian package or PPA. This will make rEFInd the default boot program. You can do the installation from either distribution, but with different consequences:

- From 14.04 -- Both distributions' kernels will show up in the rEFInd menu, so you'll be able to boot either directly; however, you'll need to add kernel options manually when you boot 15.10, at least the first time you do so. (You can run the `mkrlconf` script, which comes with rEFInd, from 15.10, to create a configuration file that obviates the need to manually modify the boot options. You'll need to copy that script from the 14.04 installation, or at least mount the 14.04 partition in 15.10 so you can access that script.)
- From 15.10 -- The configuration file created by mkrlconf will be created automatically by the package installation, so you'll be able to boot 15.10 without modifying its boot options; however, the EFI filesystem driver needed to access your 14.04 kernel will not be installed. Thus, to boot 14.04, you'll need to do so via GRUB, which should appear as an option. You can manually install the ext4fs driver, or re-install rEFInd from 14.04, if you want to be able to boot the 14.04 kernel directly from rEFInd, without using GRUB.

Note that using rEFInd will probably not work if the filesystem for your 15.10 installation is damaged. At best, it will show an option for the 15.10 kernel, but launching that kernel will fail at some point, perhaps with a message about filesystem damage. rEFInd is most likely to be helpful if the root cause is a lack of LVM support in Ubuntu 14.04 or some other glitch in the GRUB scripts for detecting Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Thank you Rod Smith a sudo update-grub did the trick and the 15.10 menu option was added to my GRUB menu!

Comment: I think what happened was that I did not have lvm2 installed under 14.04 and when I updated 14.04 it updated GRUB and couldn't see 15.10 and removed it from the boot menu.   I noticed the boot-repair utility installed lvm2 in 14.04 when I was trying to get 15.10 back and I was then able to mount my 15.10 root partition and now your update-grub suggestion worked.  Does that make sense?  Thanks again for your help!